# NullReferenceException on OpenSkeletonFrame

Tags: c#, kinect

Hello, I get a `NullReferenceException` when running this:

```
void newSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(e);
        if (first == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        /**
         * @TODO
         * obsluzyc wyjatek null reference na wypadek gdy gubi szkielet
         */ 
        long timestamp = e.OpenSkeletonFrame().Timestamp;
```

it is in the line of `long timestamp`

It occurse while 10-15 seconds if same action. For example I'm logging some data standing still. I log them in every frame. After few seconds I get the `NullReferenceException`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Yes!!! You asked the question, so you can't beat me to answering it

Comment: Since a `TimeStamp` is a measurement of time, couldn't you use a timer?

Comment: @OutlawLemur I need a timestamp. It`s a bigger thing and I need it. And it purpous is much bigger then simple timer. So this won`t solve the problem. Btw I can always find the solution for my own and still I`ll beat you :D

Comment: Danggit! I forgot about that:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I fouund answer for my problem. It is very simple.

Whe my system/machine is overloaded or it slows down from any other reason frames ain`t analyzed as fast as they sould. That whey when this lag occurs I can't open a frame. Thats why I get null.

Bellow solution of the problem

```
bool haveSkeletonData = false;
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
if (skeletonFrame != null)
{
    if ((this.skeletonData == null) || (this.skeletonData.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength))
    {
        this.skeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
    }
    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);
    haveSkeletonData = true;
}
else
{
    haveSkeletonData = false;
}
}

if (haveSkeletonData)
{
   // here i can put code that is using my timestamp 
}
```

That way I'll be safe from null and I'll be able to use my timestamp as I need to :)

Comment: Accept your own answer, you can do that